# Is it possible to encrypt the content stored in SVN?

Tags: svn

If I am storing my source code in SVN on a shared hosting company, would it be possible to encrypt the content so EVEN if someone does have access to the repo they can't see the source in plain view?

Is there a plugin for this?  Otherwise I'd imagine it would be crazy implementing this oneself!

Comment: It should be possible (on some revision control systems, depending on how they work internally): If the revision control system stores deltas (not revisions), and you don't mind leaking how many revisions there are. Then you could encrypt the deltas, and then check them into another repository. Now I can see the history (maybe checkin comments, depending on policy), without the key. But you need the key to see anything more. Diffs will work fine, and repository size will not be adversely affected, as repository compression still works as it is done locally, before encryption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct answer here is either:

1. Find a hosting provider you trust (or one that is compliant if regulatory issue are the problem)
2. Host it yourself

If the main concern is having a secure offsite backup, host the repository yourself and use someplace like [rsync.net](http://rsync.net/) to handle the backup (they are [SOX](http://www.rsync.net/resources/regulatory/sarbanesoxley.html)/[HIPAA](http://www.rsync.net/resources/regulatory/hipaa.html) compliant).  A cron job that rsyncs everything every 15 minutes should be sufficient.  The cron job can encrypt your backup before pushing it.  Just don't lose the keys/passwords.

This way Subversion doesn't need to know anything at all about your encryption scheme, and you can go about your work without having to worry about paranoia getting in the way of productivity.

**Addenda**:

Since you're doing shared hosting, and shared hosts are worthless:  Get a dedicated source control host.  Do not **ever** use a shared host for source control.  Shared hosts are notorious for losing data and making false claims about data security and backups.  Good examples of dedicated source control hosts:  [CVSDude](http://cvsdude.com/), [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/), [GitHub](http://github.com/)

Comment: I'll also add that one of the nice side-effects of distributed version control is that every clone of the repository essentially *is* a backup.  Also, I trust GitHub absolutely with virtually everything I write.  See also: http://svnhub.com/

Comment: Does github allow encrypted repos?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. You should ask the GitHub guys. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you would like to have would have to be on the client side (Obviously if you do not trust people having access to the hosted repository). Any strong cryptographic algorithm generates big variations in the output from very similar input (due to their high entropy).

That means even if you would have a solution:

- it would be a disaster in terms of performance, both computation time and storage space requirements and network bandwidth use, and
- a disaster in feature loss: server side diffs would be broken for example, you would have to make all operations on the completely decrypted files on the client side.

Weak encryption (mangling the charset for example, that would make diffs usable again) is not safe especially with source code, where braces and brackets and from there loops and any other letters can be extremely quickly decoded.

I hope this proves that going this way is not leading to any possible practical solution. Maybe I am missing something. I am looking forward to reading interesting comments on my answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's old but i find other solution for this and may help others.

Today you can get some Virtual Provate Servers (VPS) very cheap. ($5/month)

Why VPS? You can install what you want! 
(Bob Aman's answer have a very good point about shared hosts security)

1. Install TrueCrypt or other encryption system.
2. Install SVN
3. Create the SVN repository into the TrueCrypt Drive/File
4. Configure SVN to use a SSH or other secure Data Transfer method.

I configured everything with THIS article: http://cinserely.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/creating-encrypted-subversion.html

How to (4.) http://tortoisesvn.net/sasl_howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Mathew's post is for an encrypted filesystem which the hosting provider would have to provide.  That's probably the only easy way to do it.

Comment: It's not only that -- it's also storing encrypted blobs in the repository, losing all useful version tracking in the process.