# Encrypt the code while committing to cloud

Tags: svn, encryption

I am using SVN for committing my code into **"code.google.com"**. I want to secure my code. So is there any way to encrypt the code and commit. And again while checking out the code that needs to be decrypted.

So is there any way to achieve this...???

Thanq in advance,
Amar.

Comment: Doesn't Google offer HTTPS?

Comment: I need to encrypt my classes before committing the code into cloud. So If i encrypt that file its not possible to open that file through the browser. I need that feature. Is there anyway to achieve this...??? or else I need to develop my own...??? If I need to develop my own how can I start this feature...???

Comment: If I get it right: 1) You want to use open-source project hosting for a closed-source project. 2) You want to use Subversion as storage facility rather than source control tool. — I'd say the answer is that you need to spend a few days coding some witty hooks with asymmetric encryption. It's probably cheaper to just pay for a private service.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about security of your code and it's closed source, don't place it to open-source project hosting. You should either move to self-hosted solution or consider setting up Subversion server on a private VDS.

As of encrypted server-side, see the SO thread: [Is it possible to encrypt the content stored in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402471/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-the-content-stored-in-svn)

Comment: Thanq for you reply. Hay I am asking for this not only to encrypt the code also I need to learn new task. So that's y I created my own task to store the encrypted content into the cloud. Before starting the code I am just enquiring is there any other tools to implement this feature or not.

Comment: @amar see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402471/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-the-content-stored-in-svn